Indirect Concavity and Convexity of the Function $f(x, y, z) = x y^2 z^3$
I am working on determining whether the function $f(x, y, z) = x y^2 z^3$ is indirectly concave or indirectly convex on $\mathbb{R}^3_{++}$.
Definitions:

A function $f$ is said to be indirectly concave if there exist functions $F$ and $h$ such that $F$ is concave, $h$ is increasing, and $f = h \circ F$.
Similarly, $f$ is indirectly convex if there exist functions $F$ and $h$ such that $F$ is convex, $h$ is increasing, and $f = h \circ F$.

My intuition:

Since $x z^3$ is an increasing function of $x$ and $z$, and $y^2$ is convex, I initially thought that $f$ might be indirectly convex.
However, I am struggling to find appropriate functions $F$ and $h$ to explicitly show this. Moreover, I am unsure whether this function might be indirectly concave or not.

Question:

How can I determine if $f(x, y, z) = x y^2 z^3$ is indirectly convex?
Is there a method or transformation that I can use to identify $F$ and $h$, in general?
Could $f$ also be indirectly concave? If so, how would I demonstrate this?

Any insights or detailed explanations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Sounds like a fun question. What is $\mathbb{R}_{++}^3$?

@SeverinSchraven  All $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x>0, y>0, z>0$.

I don't know if it'd be any useful, but if you take $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ twice in $f = h \circ F$ then by the chain rule you have $$0 = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2} \cdot h' \circ F + \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\right)^2 \cdot h'' \circ F$$ thus $h'' \circ F$ is non-negative if $F$ is concave/non-positive if $F$ is convex whenever $\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\right)^2 \neq 0$ since every other function involved in the RHS has a predetermined sign with the assumptions given. 1/2

This would make $h$ concave on the range of $F$ if $F$ is convex and vice-versa, but again I don't know how useful that info would be... I could also be wrong. 2/2

But I do not know whether these functions are differentiable or not. Can I @BrunoB ?

Given the polynomial nature of $f$, I'd say there's a high likelihood that $h$ and $F$ need to be smooth, or at least that if there's no smooth pair then there's no such pair at all, though that's just my intuition.
